# Lightswitch 2012 Menu and Ribbon missing

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I am using Lightswitch as shipped with Visual Studio 2012 on a Windows 7 machine, and even with simple tutorial projects, the top Ribbon control and left Menu do not appear.
In addition, under Properties, Application Type, I have options for Desktop or Web, but not the additional controls for Application Server or Azure.
This is a new dev machine, I confirmed that IIS is on and running, but may be missing a configuration step or service.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Yann Duran, one of the moderators of the the LightSwitch forum on MSDN.  He said that I was following 2011 tutorials, and needed to change the theme from the new one that ships with VS 2012.  I changed the Shell value (under Properties, General Properties) to Lightswitch Standard Shell and everything works fine.

While that fixed my problem, it raises a new question.  Why wouldn't a vanilla tutorial for Lightswitch produce a working application on VS 2012 using the new theme?  A question for another day, perhaps.